# Deploying laravel 5.4 project in shared host

Tags: php, laravel-5, frameworks

I‘m facing some problems with my Laravel 5.4 project. I’ve created my project on localhost everything is working, no problems. Now I need this project to work on shared host. So, I rent a server, create database, create a folder in the same level as `public_html`, upload all files and folders (except public folder and its content) in this folder. Public folder content I put in `public_html` folder. I also make changes in my `index.php` file in public folder and changed two lines:

```
require __DIR__.'/../my_folder/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../my_folder/bootstrap/app.php';
```

In `.env` file besides database connection lines, I’ve also changed line `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=localhost`

When I try to run my project on shared host, the starting page works perfect, but when I try to navigate to other pages, I‘m getting error connecting with routes (`NotFoundHttpException` in `RouteCollection.php`)

My `.httacces` file content is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Maybe I need some changes here? I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you just uploading all the files? How are you deploying your project?

Comment: Yes, i'm just uploading according to all rules. Project files and database. Project works perfect on localhost. I thing, i'm missing some small details and im still trying to figure it out....

Comment: Finally, i figure it out. Ive had a feeling, that the problem is in links. In localhost i have to write /../my_folder/public... in shared host i do not need my_folder/public.
Thanks all to all effords :) Now everything works.